# Corrupt PDF with \includegraphics

Tags: errors, luatex, includegraphics

I'm trying to include an image that is in .pdf format within my document. I am including lots of images in my real document with others displaying correctly: I need to retain their high quality hence my not converting them to .jpg or .png. But on certain occasions the images do not show up in the document and I get the following error in Adobe Acrobat Reader when I scroll to a given page:

```
There was an error processing a page. 
There was a problem reading this document (135).
```

I need to use `\includegraphics` so I can crop the PDF, so using `\pdfpages` isn't an option, although the latter does work as expected.

My MWE (called `problem.tex` here) is simple enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
  \includegraphics[width=.8\linewidth]{page.pdf}
\end{document}
```

When I run `lualatex problem` it compiles as I expect it to:

```
This is LuaHBTeX, Version 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./problem.tex
LaTeX2e <2020-10-01> patch level 2


 L3 programming layer <2020-10-27> xparse <2020-03-03>
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/luatex.def)))
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3backend/l3backend-luatex.def)
No file problem.aux.
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[Loading MPS to PDF converter (version 2006.09.02).]
) (/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/epstopdf-pkg/epstopdf-base.sty
(/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/tex/latex/latexconfig/epstopdf-sys.cfg))
[1{/usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}<./page
.pdf>] (./problem.aux))
 406 words of node memory still in use:
   3 hlist, 1 vlist, 1 rule, 2 glue, 3 kern, 1 glyph, 4 attribute, 48 glue_spec
, 4 attribute_list, 1 write nodes
   avail lists: 2:27,3:10,4:1,5:22,6:2,7:30,9:28
</usr/local/texlive/2020/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/lm/lmroman10-regular.
otf>
Output written on problem.pdf (1 page, 611633 bytes).
Transcript written on problem.log.
```

Incidentally, if I compile the MWE using `xelatex` there are no problems. Sadly I need the functionality of LuaLaTeX for other parts of the document.

I also checked the document for errors in Acrobat Pro's Preflight and it shows an error in the PDF syntax: `Unable to analyze the content stream on page 1; parse error: "Dictionary keys must be direct name objects"`. My feeling is that LuaLaTeX is somehow not handling the PDF insert properly.

Since the image I'm trying to include is required to recreate the MWE, I've uploaded everything to a [Bitbucket repo](https://bitbucket.org/longwayahead/latex-problem/src/master/). There you'll find the .tex MWE as `problem.tex`, the file I'm trying to include `page.pdf` and a sample of the output file that has the error in question.

Am I doing something stupid? Any ideas why I'm getting an error and the image isn't showing up? Thanks!

Comment: Do you have an example of a PDF you are including? Is it really a PDF file?

Comment: pdfpages uses \includegraphics too, so I don't see how it can work if the later fail (and it fails for me too). As xelatex seems to be able to handle your pdf you could use xelatex and standalone class to recreate a repairpage.pdf and use this then with lualatex in your document.

Comment: @OlegLobachev Yes, it's in the Bitbucket repo. Link is in the second last paragraph ^

Comment: @pinecone: Thanks! Can verify for LuaHBTeX 1.12.0 (TeX Live 2020). It works with XeTeX.

Comment: Running over the offending PDF file helps: after `ps2pdf page.pdf page-gs.pdf` the page-gs.pdf can be included properly, everything works well with LuaTeX.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks for your suggestion and for confirming the problem is reproducible. Reading up about the standalone package from its docs on CTAN doesn't really offer many clues about how it might work in practice in this instance. Could I compile with xelatex first on the standalone doc then run the usual lualatex compile?

Comment: @OlegLobachev Thanks for your suggestion which works a charm on my system too. Any ideas whether by using `ps2pdf` the quality of the original is affected in anyway? I just note the reduction in file size, not that that's always a concrete indicator. Thanks!

Comment: @pinecone Your original file has some additional metadata for the image which is dropped by `ps2pdf`. (When the picture was created/modified/which lens was used/etc.) You will have to decide for yourself is that's a significant loss.

Comment: @MarcelKrüger but it looks like a luatex bug that it gets confused by this, it mixes the metadata in the dictionary.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I am currently testing a fix.

Comment: Possible fix submitted upstream under https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/dev-luatex/2021-February/006455.html

Comment: Thanks! For the sake of completeness my workaround was simply to expunge the metadata from the image/inserted PDF. Works great. Thanks @MarcelKrüger for the future bug fix